# how to insert Json data into postgres DB

Tags: python, json, postgresql, python-3.6

I'm trying to get the movie data from TMDB(The Movie database) by hitting the tmdb api and storing those results in json. Now i have a table in postgres to store these results

I have the tmdb data like this

```
'tmdb': [{'id': 47943, 'video': False, 'vote_count': 104, 'vote_average': 6.8, 'title': 'With a Friend Like Harry...', 'release_date': '2000-08-15', 'original_language': 'fr', 'original_title': 'Harry, un ami qui vous veut du bien', 'genre_ids': [18, 53], 'backdrop_path': '/tzf358ft10Mr7P4X5t1z9FkFjvx.jpg', 'adult': False, 'overview': "Harry knew Michel in high school; they meet again by accident, Harry inserts himself in Michel's life... and things take a sinister turn.", 'poster_path': '/z9dikT4piSwPJYoFVi4qqcfxJe1.jpg', 'popularity': 5.683}]
```

I am calling the below function before inserting to get the data from api

```
tmdb_data = get_tmdb_data(id_titles,content_type)
```

This is the insert code:

```
if bool(tmdb_data):
                sql = """
                    INSERT INTO titles_tmdb(id_titles,tmdb_id,title,description,release_date,director,
                    poster_url,backdrop_url,trailer_url,popularity,dt_utc,tmdb_data)
                    VALUES ("{0}","{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}","{5}","{6}","{7}","{8}","{9}",now() at time zone 'utc',
                    "{10}")
                    """.format(id_titles, tmdb_data['tmdb_id'], tmdb_data['title'], tmdb_data['description'],
                        tmdb_data['release_date'], tmdb_data['director'], tmdb_data['poster_path'], 
                        tmdb_data['backdrop_path'], tmdb_data['trailer_url'], tmdb_data['popularity'],
                        tmdb_data['tmdb'])

                db.engine.execute(sqlalchemy.text(sql))
```

I am facing a psycopg2.ProgrammingError: while inserting the whole json file

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "Harry"
LINE 5: ...P4X5t1z9FkFjvx.jpg', 'adult': False, 'overview': "Harry knew...
                                                             ^
 [SQL: '\n\t\t\t\t\tINSERT INTO titles_tmdb(id_titles,tmdb_id,title,description,release_date,director,\n\t\t\t\t\tposter_url,backdrop_url,trailer_url,popularity,dt_utc,tmdb_data)\n\t\t\t\t\tVALUES ("tt0216800","47943","With a Friend Like Harry...","Harry knew Michel in high school; they meet again by accident, Harry inserts himself in Michels life... and things take a sinister turn.","2000-08-15","Dominik Moll","https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/z9dikT4piSwPJYoFVi4qqcfxJe1.jpg","https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/tzf358ft10Mr7P4X5t1z9FkFjvx.jpg","NA","5.683",now() at time zone \'utc\',\n\t\t\t\t\t"[{\'id\': 47943, \'video\': False, \'vote_count\': 104, \'vote_average\': 6.8, \'title\': \'With a Friend Like Harry...\', \'release_date\': \'2000-08-15\', \'original_language\': \'fr\', \'original_title\': \'Harry, un ami qui vous veut du bien\', \'genre_ids\': [18, 53], \'backdrop_path\': \'/tzf358ft10Mr7P4X5t1z9FkFjvx.jpg\', \'adult\': False, \'overview\': "Harry knew Michel in high school; they meet again by accident, Harry inserts himself in Michel\'s life... and things take a sinister turn.", \'poster_path\': \'/z9dikT4piSwPJYoFVi4qqcfxJe1.jpg\', \'popularity\': 5.683}]")\n\t\t\t\t\t'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

I think i am facing the error with the quotes in the json file while inserting. can you please tell me how to ignore it or how to solve it. thanks in advance

Comment: Never use string formatting to inject values into SQL statements.

Comment: Check the [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql)